# error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol For Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, winrm

I am using WinRM protocol for remote connection from Linux to Windows. So, on running the following command:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName x.x.x.x -Credential $credential -UseSSL -SessionOption $so -Authentication Basic
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Connecting to remote server x.x.x.x failed with the following error message: error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I am not getting any leads on this. Can anyone help how can I debug it further?

Comment: UseSSL actually uses either TLS 1.2 or 1.3 since SSL is obsolete.  TLS 1.2 or 1.3 only uses certain encryption algorithms.  May older encryption algorithms are obsolete due to algorithm being prone to hackers.  Also some encryption algorithms can only be used on TLS 1.2. others on TLS 1.3, and some on both.  The encryption algorithms is in the certificate. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true).

Comment: There are also different types of Authentication and error could mean you are using wrong authentication type.  Between linux and windows you should be using OAUTH 2.0 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0).  the error message could mean either TLS is failing or Authentication is failing.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management?force_isolation=true